# Execute sql script with multiple statements in Spring

Tags: spring

How to execute a sql script with multiple statements, where the last statement returns the result with Spring getSimpleJdbcTemplate? I don't ask for to split the script in a list of queries and excute each by loop over the list.

```
  String query="";
        EncodedResource resource = new EncodedResource(context.getResource("/resources/spring/sql/my.sql"), "UTF-8");
        try {
            LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(resource.getReader());
            query =JdbcTestUtils.readScript(lnr);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace;

        }
        return (String)getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(query, String.class, new MapSqlParameterSource());
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the ScriptUtils class from spring-jdbc, available since version 4.0.3, like this:

```
ClassPathResource schemaResource = new ClassPathResource("schema.sql");
ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(myDataSource.getConnection(), schemaResource);
```

Note! This will regretfully **not** return the result of the last statement. I would consider separating the script and the last statement of the script if a result is required.

The ScriptUtils class contains methods for reading and splitting SQL scripts.